# slickGoTo not working when responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

```
$('div.test').slick({
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '18%',
    slidesToShow: 3,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1
        }
    }, {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1
        }
    }]
});
$('div.test').slick('slickGoTo', 4);
```

Go to http://jsfiddle.net/wzL4ztLg/

When you run the demo in a full sized screen, slickGoTo works as expected. When you shrink the frame down and hit run, slickGoTo doesn't seem to work.

I've also found if you keep the frame small but remove the responsive settings, slickGoTo works again - http://jsfiddle.net/wzL4ztLg/1/

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this bug, when I remove the responsive settings 'slickGoTo' works again. Have been looking for a fix for hours but no results.

Quick note, if you use it with a click handler it works (with responsive settings):

```
$('.slider').on('click', function(event) {
  $(".slider").slick("slickGoTo", 3, true);
});
```